# Шагреневая кожа

Tags: этимология

Насколько я знаю, шагреневая кожа делалась из шкуры акулы. А почему тогда такое название — "шагреневая"? Что оно означает?

Comment: Это кожа акулы или ската с характерными шешуйками. Сейчас почти не производится из за сложности выделки

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А кто сказал, что из акулы? Шагрень - фр. chagrin — мягкая шероховатая кожа (козлиная, баранья, конская); также технология тиснения кожи, используется при обработке кож с природными дефектами для изготовления обуви и отдельных видов одежды.

[Шагреневая кожа](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/222459)

Роман "Шагреневая кожа"-La Peau de Chagrin. Название романа не поддаётся точному переводу. По-французски "chagrin" означает и сорт кожи, и "печаль". Его можно было бы перевести как "Кожа печали".

Вот в словаре:
[Шагреневая кожа](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/3060/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F).     Шагреневая кожа в прямом смысле слова — хорошо обработанная кожа из козлиной (не козьей) шкуры, которая используется в скорняжном производстве. 
Иносказательно: о том, что необратимо и постоянно уменьшается, исчезает (время, ресурсы и пр.).

Comment: >Иносказательно: о том, что необратимо и постоянно уменьшается, исчезает (время, ресурсы и пр.).

А почему эта шагреневая кожа *постоянно уменьшается*? Откуда вообще именно такая аналогия? Если это, как описано, шероховатая кожа... По какой причине она уменьшается?

Comment: Вообще-то у кожи есть такое свойство - сжиматься,высыхать от времени(у меня ботинки год полежали-не могу надеть), а у Бальзака это вообще артифакт, т.е. связано с волшебством - останавливает человека в его непомерных желаниях, каждое желание уносит время жизни.

Comment: А я тоже читала когда-то, что из акулы. Но, может, это было в каком-то переносном значении, сейчас не вспомню.